# Binary To Corresponding ASCII String Conversion

Tags: c#

Hi i was able to convert a `ASCII` string to binary using a `binarywriter`  .. as `10101011` . im required back to convert `Binary` ---> `ASCII` string .. any idea how to do it ?

Comment: System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data) ?

Comment: What's wrong with Convert.ToBase64String(data)? Why are you shoving the bytes into a stream, and reading those bytes back again from that stream?

Comment: `ToBase64String` gives me a Base64 value not a Text !

Comment: `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString` giving me back the binary in string not Text Representation :-S

Comment: **What do you want to do?** Just say what do you have, and what do you want. If you're using ToBase64String, **of course the result will be in base-64**.

Comment: I you're trying to get banned from asking questions, you're a great job. Stop asking the same thing again and again!

Comment: @Martinho I have a Binary String `'101010'` -> Need `'ABC'` representation of it !

Comment: @Sudantha how exactly `101010` is `ABC`? If you'll describe the algorithm maybe someone can help you implement it.

Comment: @Sudantha - Do you have a binary string "01001101" or a byte array? Your question says it is already a byte array; thus GetString... if you need to convert the string representation of binary in to a byte array then that is a different issue.

Comment: @Shadow - `010000010100001001000011` --> `ABC`  - NOW HAPPY ?

Comment: @Sudantha: see, wasn't that hard, was it?

Comment: @Coder - Thats the exact point ! i have a `String` .. how to take it exactly to a `byte[]` ?

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2206.htm algo i used to create the binary string

Comment: Calgary beat me to it, see your original question for the almost same code just with some error handling.

Comment: From your multiple re-tries a this, your first sentence is wrong. A binarywriter does not produce a _string_ of `0` and `1`s

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should do the trick... or at least get you started...

```
public Byte[] GetBytesFromBinaryString(String binary)
{
  var list = new List<Byte>();

  for (int i = 0; i < binary.Length; i += 8)
  {
    String t = binary.Substring(i, 8);

    list.Add(Convert.ToByte(t, 2));
  }

  return list.ToArray();
}
```

Once the binary string has been converted to a byte array, finish off with

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

So...

```
var data = GetBytesFromBinaryString("010000010100001001000011");
var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot Coder.. Exactly what i needed and working awesomely !  .. i  was trying whole day with a  blackout and finally !! thanks a lot ! :D

Comment: @Sudantha: I have merged your two identical questions; you might want to re-accept this answer (it was accepted on the other question).

Comment: it works thank you. my code is 7 length so i only change 8 to 7.

Answer (score 7):

If you have ASCII charters only you could use `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` and `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`.

```
var text = "Test";
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
var newText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is complete code for your [answer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/BinaryStringFun.aspx)

```
FileStream iFile = new FileStream(@"c:\test\binary.dat",
FileMode.Open);

long lengthInBytes = iFile.Length;

BinaryReader bin = new BinaryReader(aFile);

byte[] byteArray = bin.ReadBytes((int)lengthInBytes);

System.Text.Encoding encEncoder = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;

string str = encEncoder.GetString(byteArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take this as a simple example:

```
public void ByteToString()
{
   Byte[] arrByte = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 };

   string x = Convert.ToBase64String(arrByte);
}
```

This linked answer has interesting details about this kind of conversion:

[binary file to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980182/binary-file-to-string/2980254#2980254)

Comment: HI leniel im having a string how to convert it to `byte[]` i used `Encoding.ASCHII` .... but it gives a junk ~

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes instead of using the built in tools it's better to use "custom" code.. try this function:

```
public string BinaryToString(string binary)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(binary))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("binary");

    if ((binary.Length % 8) != 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Binary string invalid (must divide by 8)", "binary");

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < binary.Length; i += 8)
    {
        string section = binary.Substring(i, 8);
        int ascii = 0;
        try
        {
            ascii = Convert.ToInt32(section, 2);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Binary string contains invalid section: " + section, "binary");
        }
        builder.Append((char)ascii);
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Tested with `010000010100001001000011` it returned `ABC` using the "raw" ASCII values.