# Binary to Text Translation C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Binary To Corresponding ASCII String Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006425/binary-to-corresponding-ascii-string-conversion)

I converted a string to a sequence of ones and zeros using the algorithm found [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2206.htm).

Now I'm trying to convert it back. How can I do that?