# C# Function to translate Binary-Code

Tags: c#, binary, translate

Right now I try to write a C# Program to translate 8 Base Binary into Text.

But I guess I am not experienced enough with C# to truly make it Work.

I think the code I come up with, should, from a logical Point-of-View somewhat do what I want, but the Syntax isn't properly doing it, since don´t know it better.

This is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class binaryTranslate
{
    public int convertBin(string CodeInput)
    {
        int [] code = CodeInput.ToArray();
        int CodeCount = code.ToString().Length;
        int EightBaseSegAmount = CodeCount / 8;
        int ByteCapacity = 8;
        StringBuilder translated = new StringBuilder();

        for (var i = 1; i < EightBaseSegAmount + 1; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder Byte = new StringBuilder(ByteCapacity);
            int ByteStart = (i * 8) - 8;
            int ByteEnd = (i * 8) - 1;
            int ByteIncrement = 1;

                for (var j = ByteStart ; j < ByteEnd + 1; j++)
                {
                    Byte.Append(code[j]);
                }

            for (var k = 0; k > 7; k++)
            {
                int BitValue = 128;


                if (Byte[k] == 1)
                {
                    if (k > 0)
                    {
                        int Squared = Math.Pow(2, k);
                        ByteIncrement += BitValue / Squared;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ByteIncrement += BitValue; 
                    }
                }

            }
            char toSymbol = Convert.ToChar(ByteIncrement);
            translated.Append(toSymbol);
        }

        return translated;
    }

    public static int Main()
    {
        convertBin("010010000110000101101100011011000110111100100001");
    }
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? Describe the problem in more detail rather than just saying "Syntax isn´t properly doing it".

Comment: You can try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006425/binary-to-corresponding-ascii-string-conversion)

Comment: `convertBin` should be static, as i'm assuming this is a console application. Also your program won't output anything.

Comment: Looks like we have enough solutions now; welrocken's looks very well thought through, and reasonably efficient as well. I could add my own solution in F# but I guess it would be off-topic… :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code won't compile. Here are the errors/mistakes.

- The first one is, at the first line of your function, you are converting the input string to an array using `String.ToArray()`, which returns a `char[]` but your try to assign it to a variable (code) typed `int[]`. You can solve this by replacing the `int[]` with either `char[]` or `var`.
- The second one is, inside the second for loop `(k = 0; k > 7)`, you use `Math.Pow()` and assign it's return value to an `int` variable (Squared). But `Math.Pow` returns double. You can solve this by casting the return value of `Math.Pow` to `int`. Like; `int Squared = (int)Math.Pow(2, k);`
- The last thing is not easily solvable like the first two because, your code is not exactly correct. You are trying to return something called `translated`, which is a variable of type `StringBuilder`. But your function is defined to return an `int`.

Now these were compile errors. There are a bunch of logical and decision errors/mistakes. Your algorithm also isn't very correct.

Here is a sample code you can use/examine. I'd like to help you further, why your code was incorrect, what was your design mistakes etc. if you want to.

```
class binaryTranslate
{
    public enum IncompleteSegmentBehavior
    {
        Skip = 0,
        ZerosToStart = 1,
        ZerosToEnd = 2
    }

    private byte ConvertBinstrToByte(string sequence)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sequence))
            return 0; // Throw?

        if (sequence.Length != sizeof(byte) * 8)
            return 0; // Throw?

        const char zero = '0';
        const char one = '1';

        byte value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Length; i++)
        {
            if (sequence[i] != zero && sequence[i] != one)
                return 0; // Throw

            value |= (byte)((sequence[i] - zero) << (7 - i));
        }

        return value;
    }

    private string HandleIncompleteSegment(string segment, int segmentSize, IncompleteSegmentBehavior behavior)
    {
        string result = null;

        var zeroAppender = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < segmentSize - segment.Length; i++)
            zeroAppender.Append('0');

        var zeros = zeroAppender.ToString();

        switch (behavior)
        {
            case IncompleteSegmentBehavior.Skip:
                break;
            case IncompleteSegmentBehavior.ZerosToStart:
                result = zeros + result;
                break;
            case IncompleteSegmentBehavior.ZerosToEnd:
                result = result + zeros;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public byte[] ConvertBinstrToBytes(string binarySequence, IncompleteSegmentBehavior behavior = IncompleteSegmentBehavior.Skip)
    {
        var segmentSize = sizeof(byte) * 8;

        var sequenceLength = binarySequence.Length;

        var numberOfBytes = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)sequenceLength / segmentSize);
        var bytes = new byte[numberOfBytes];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBytes; i++)
        {
            var charactersLeft = sequenceLength - i * segmentSize;
            var segmentLength = (charactersLeft < segmentSize ? charactersLeft : segmentSize);
            var segment = binarySequence.Substring(i * segmentSize, segmentLength);

            if (charactersLeft < segmentSize)
            {
                segment = HandleIncompleteSegment(segment, segmentSize, behavior);
                if (segment == null)
                    continue;
            }

            bytes[i] = ConvertBinstrToByte(segment);
        }

        return bytes;
    }
}
```

This code passes these assertions.

```
var bytes = new binaryTranslate()
    .ConvertBinstrToBytes("00000000");

Assert.Equal(bytes.Length, 1);
Assert.Equal(bytes[0], 0b00000000);

bytes = new binaryTranslate()
    .ConvertBinstrToBytes("10000000");

Assert.Equal(bytes.Length, 1);
Assert.Equal(bytes[0], 0b10000000);

bytes = new binaryTranslate()
    .ConvertBinstrToBytes("11111111");

Assert.Equal(bytes.Length, 1);
Assert.Equal(bytes[0], 0b11111111);

bytes = new binaryTranslate()
    .ConvertBinstrToBytes("00000001");

Assert.Equal(bytes.Length, 1);
Assert.Equal(bytes[0], 0b00000001);

bytes = new binaryTranslate()
    .ConvertBinstrToBytes("1100110000110011");

Assert.Equal(bytes.Length, 2);
Assert.Equal(bytes[0], 0b11001100);
Assert.Equal(bytes[1], 0b00110011);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really converting to a string the code should look like this

```
namespace binaryTranslate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //convertBin("01001000 01100001 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100001");
            string results = BinaryTranslate.convertBin(new byte[] { 0x44, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x21 });
        }
    }
   public  class BinaryTranslate
    {
        public static string convertBin(byte[] CodeInput)
        {
            return string.Join("", CodeInput.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick.

```
public static string FromBinary(string binary)
{
    int WordLength = 8;

    binary = binary.Replace(' ', '');
    while(binary.Length % WordLength != 0)
        binary += "0";

    string output = String.Empty;
    string word = String.Empty;
    int offset = 0;

    while(offset < binary.Length)
    {
        int tmp = 0;
        word = binary.Substring(offset, 8);
        for(int i=0; i<(WordLength - 1); i++)
            if(word[i] == '1')
                tmp += (int) Math.Pow(2, i);

        output += Convert.ToChar(tmp);
        offset += WordLength;
    }

    return output;
}
```