# how to convert an array of integers (1s and 0s) to their ascii equivalents in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, binary, ascii, data-conversion

I have an array of integer 1s and 0s (possibly need to get converted to byte type?). I have used [an online ASCII to binary generator](https://www.branah.com/ascii-converter) to get the equivalent binary of this 6 digit letter sequence:

`abcdef` should equal `011000010110001001100011011001000110010101100110` in binary. So in c#, my array is `[0,1,1,0,0,0,0...]`, built by:

```
int[] innerArr = new int[48]; 
for (int i = 0; i < 48); i++) {
    int innerIsWhite = color.val[0] > 200 ? 0 : 1;
    innerArr[i] = innerIsWhite;
}
```

I want to take this array, and convert it into `abcdef` (and be able to do the opposite).

How do I do this? Is there a better way to be storing these ones and zeros.

Comment: In terms of better ways to store sequences of bits, rather than a string, you could use a [BitArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006425/binary-to-corresponding-ascii-string-conversion
First Answer has the information you need

Comment: @mheavers I can verify you can create a `BitArray` with 48 elements - `new BitArray(48)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using *Linq* and `Convert`:

```
  source = "abcdef";

  // 011000010110001001100011011001000110010101100110 
  string encoded = string.Concat(source
    .Select(c => Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));

  // If we want an array
  byte[] encodedArray = encoded
    .Select(c => (byte) (c - '0'))
    .ToArray();

  // string from array
  string encodedFromArray = string.Concat(encodedArray);

  // abcdef
  string decoded = string.Concat(Enumerable
    .Range(0, encoded.Length / 8)
    .Select(i => (char) Convert.ToByte(encoded.Substring(i * 8, 8), 2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input is a bit string, then you can use a method like below to convert that into character string

```
public static string GetStringFromAsciiBitString(string bitString) {
    var asciiiByteData = new byte[bitString.Length / 8];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < asciiiByteData.Length; ++i, j+= 8)
        asciiiByteData[i] = Convert.ToByte(bitString.Substring(j, 8), 2);
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(asciiiByteData);
}
```

The above code simply uses the `Convert.ToByte` method asking it to do a base-2 string to byte conversion. Then using `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`, you get the string representation from the byte array

In my code, I presume your bit string is clean (multiple of 8 and with only 0s and 1s), in production grade code you will have to sanitize your input.