# Convert binary data in a text file to text format

Tags: c#, string, binary, data-conversion

I want to read a .txt file containing "0100100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000101011101101111011100100110110001100100" and want to convert this binary data to corresponding text format "HelloWorld" in c#
Please help

[Binary To Corresponding ASCII String Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006425/binary-to-corresponding-ascii-string-conversion)

This is not giving me answers.

Comment: *This is not giving me answers.* - the accepted answer of the duplicate target (which is almost identical to the answer below) converts the string that you gave as an example to "Hello World". If this is not what you want, you need to explain what else you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

1. split it into 8 character length chunks (one byte each chunk)
2. convert each chunk with `Convert.ToByte(string input, int base)` into type byte
3. convert the bytes into text with `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte[] input)`

https://dotnetfiddle.net/w37fvg

```
string input = "0100100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000101011101101111011100100110110001100100";
List<byte> bList = new List<byte>();
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 8)
{
    bList.Add(Convert.ToByte(input.Substring(i, 8), 2));
}
string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bList.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: the above program gives Exception:  System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Comment: already handled in [System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string. in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67875389)

Comment: @KeerthiVasan the code above gives no exception - just look at the fiddle. But you have to make sure that `input.length%8==0`