# Extract XML From Binary

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a binary file that contains xmldata in bytes 2-43. 
How would I go about extracting that data to a file?

I am able to extract small integer fields doing something like this:

`Row.TenderNumber = BitConverter.ToInt16(Row.RawBytesraw, 44);`

However, I don't know how to extract xml data from this file.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ought to work

```
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(<byte[] here>))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var buffer = new char[41];
        stream.Seek(<offset where string begins>, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        reader.Read(buffer, 0, 41);
        <mystringVariable> = new string(buffer);
    }
```

I wrote it in C# but you get the idea.

Comment: So in your example, how would I take bytes 2-43 from Row.RawBytesraw and output that to a variable?

Comment: actually, I mean if you have the array of bytes that only contains bytes 2 - 43, you can just return new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(myBytes)).ReadToEnd(); -- this will autodetect the encoding etc -- now that will only be a string of course -- optionally you could just skip the string and pass the memory stream into your xml parser -- or you could keep the string and pass it into your xml parser instead. -- Just a matter of choice.

Answer (score 1):

xml data is just text with correct formatting. If you can extract bytes from file, you can convert them into string. And string can be XML.

Have a look on this question: [binary file to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980182/binary-file-to-string)

Comment: I don't understand what you linked. I mentioned it was a file, but it is actually coming from a database. When I attempted to implement what was in your link, it was just blank.